# How to use Delegate in iOS

Tags: ios, delegates

you can see this code :

```
#import "EgKernalVClr.h"

@class EgCoreNavigationItemCustomView ;
@class EgCoreNavigationLeftBarCustomView ;
@class EgCoreNavigationRightBarCustomView ;
@class EgCoreNavigationItemBarCustomViewModel ;


@protocol EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate ;

@interface EgCoreVClr : EgKernalVClr{
@protected
    EgCoreNavigationItemCustomView *_navigationItemCustonView ;
    EgCoreNavigationLeftBarCustomView *_navigationLeftBarCustonView ;
    EgCoreNavigationRightBarCustomView *_navigationRightBarCustonView ;
}

@property (nonatomic , assign) EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate delegate ;//Error
@property (nonatomic , assign) BOOL autoAdjustLeftBarCustomView ;
@property (nonatomic , assign) BOOL hiddenLeftBarCustomView ;
@property (nonatomic , strong) EgCoreNavigationItemBarCustomViewModel *navigationItemCustomViewModel ;

- (void) addRightCustomViewWithModel:(EgCoreNavigationItemBarCustomViewModel*)customViewModel ;

@end




@protocol EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate <NSObject>
- (BOOL) leftTriggerAction:(EgCoreNavigationLeftBarCustomView*)sender withEgCoreVClr:(EgCoreVClr *)egCoreVClr ;
- (void) rightTriggerAction:(EgCoreNavigationRightBarCustomView*)sender withEgCoreVClr:(EgCoreVClr *)egCoreVClr ;
@end
```

this code :@property (nonatomic , assign) EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate delegate ;//Error

the Xcode throw error : Unknow type name 'EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate' ;

Why did the statement there is a problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define delegate properties as follow :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate> delegate;
```

And call it like this in your class :

```
// Notify delegate if requested
if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(bugReporterWillShowForm:)]) {
    [_delegate yourProtocolMethodWithOrWithoutParams];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check `_delegate` for `nil` before checking `respondsToSelector` – sending messages to nil will return 0 in this context, and therefore the `if` won't trigger if the `_delegate` is `nil` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`delegate` must be typed `object that conforms to protocol`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<EgCoreVClrNavClrDelegate> delegate;
```

and usually you want the property to be `weak`.

Comment: Not usually, but you have to set it to weak to avoid retain cycle

Comment: this is what you usually want.